# How will my vBulletin users know they have a paid subscription

Tags: vbulletin

Ok so after experimenting with vBulletin's paid subscription I am confused by one thing.  How will the user know they have purchased a subscription?  I get the confirmation emails, success page, etc.  But after all of that is complete, I see nothing different in the user CP.  And even worse, I can still purchase the same subscription again.  Is this expected behavior or a bug in my installation?

FYI when I view the user in the admin control panel I see the user has in fact paid for a subscription.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This would be resolved by creating a new user group for the paid users (donor or premium member). Then when you setup your paid subscription you can tell it to change the member group for the user who just bought the subscription. This way you can tell, the member can tell, and anyone else on your forum can tell.

Answer (score 0):

When the person goes into the new user group you can assign a custom title and image.  That way their posts in the forum will look different.

You can also grant access to different content in the CMS and Forums based on that new user group.